# Suave.io: using pathScan and request together

Tags: suave

I'm just getting up and running with Suave.io. I'm sure this will become clearer as I dig more into Applicatives - but from a high level I can't see how to write a `pathScan` rule that applies the `request` applicative too. All examples I'm found only do one or the other. In both cases they are applied to a function taking arguments - so presumably the arguments would be combined somehow too.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Both `pathScan` and `request` take a function that produces a web part, so they cannot be nicely chained using `>>=`. Instead, you can nest one inside the other (I think the order does not really matter here):

```
pathScan "/some/%d" (fun num ->
  request (fun r -> 
    OK(sprintf "%d - %A" num r.url)))
```

Comment: Thanks. As is typical I arrived at the same conclusion *just* after prompting you on twitter! I don't know how I missed this the first time around. Seems obvious now.