# Aggregating info from request in Suave

Tags: f#, suave

I am building an authenticated web API using Suave, and I often stumble on the problem of aggregating infos throughout different functions

```
pathScan Navigation.playersAvailables GetGame >>= getInSession >>= (fun (gameId,playerInSession) -> //access to both gameId and player in session)
```

signatures :

```
getGame : HttpContext -> Async<HttpContext option>
getInSession : HttpContext -> Async<HttpContext option>
```

- getGame take id from httpContext.request.querystring getInSession
- take sessionId from httpContext.cookie

The only thing I found in order to do that was to store infos in the userDataDictionnary :

```
Writers.setUserData "player"  { playerId= playersId; socialId=socialId; username = username}
```

And to retrieve it in the other function but it looks pretty nasty to me :

```
let player = x.userState.["player"] :?> PlayerSession
//do some other stuff now that we have the current player
```

Is there another way of doing that? I would like to have pure functions like 
getGameId and get Session, etc.. and to be able to compose them as I wish to process my different routes :

```
pathScan Navigation.playersAvailables GetGame >>= getInSession >>= (fun (gameId,playerInSession) -> //access to both gameId and player in session)
pathScan Navigation.otherRoute GetGame >>= (fun (gameId) -> //process gameId)
pathScan Navigation.otherRoute2 getInSession >>= (fun (sessionId) -> //process sessionId to do some other stuff)
```

I am afraid that what I need is a day talk with some real functionnal programmer..

Comment: While I don't know Suave, in general I'd recommend building applications from building blocks (functions) that are decoupled from any particular hosting technology (Suave, Web API, WPF, whatever). Write your functions with the minimal data they need, and *then* figure out how to compose them.

Comment: Actually, this is what i tried to do using (fun (gameId,playerInSession) -> //access to both gameId and player in session ) but before coming there i need to gather informations from suave framework.

Comment: A very unclear question: not quite clear what you're looking to do, the essence of the question is masked by all the details of your domain. Can you, perhaps, create a minimal abstract example?

Comment: hum I tried my best to make it clear!

Comment: Which version of Suave do you use? (There is a difference in the operator >>=)

Comment: Suave version = 0.32.1

Answer (score 0):

`setUserData` is a pure function - [src](https://github.com/SuaveIO/suave/blob/d7535cf020505f5588b92f5f3b5983221012d735/src/Suave/Combinators.fs#L75-L77).

Not sure if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31785823/57883) is still current but it says `pathScan` and `>>=` cannot be nicely chained. However I think the `Writers.setUserData` you are using may be able to accomplish it.

Accessing an object bag to pull things out isn't lovely.

how about:

```
let (|ParseInt|_|) =
    function
    | "" | null -> None
    | x ->
        match Int32.TryParse x with
        | true, i -> Some i
        | _ -> None


let (|HasParam|_|) name (ctx:HttpContext) =
    ctx.request.queryParam name
    |> function
        |Choice1Of2 value ->
            Some value
        | _ -> None

let playersAvailablePart:WebPart =
    function
    //access to both gameId and player in session
    |HasParam "inSession" playerInSession & HasParam "gameId" gameId as ctx ->
        // do your processing here, sample return:
        OK "we had all the required important parts" ctx
    // or an example of something more strongly typed
    | HasParam "inSession" (ParseInt playerInSession) & HasParam "gameId" (ParseInt gameId) as ctx ->
        // do your processing here, sample return:
        OK "we had all the required important parts" ctx
    | ctx -> never ctx
```

This doesn't exactly work if the values aren't in the queryParameters, but you can adapt it to where they are