# What is the simplest way to check that an incoming request contains a certain header value

Tags: f#, suave

I have a simple Suave.io server in the form:

```
let Ok o = o |> JsonConvert.SerializeObject |> Successful.OK
let NotOk o = o |> JsonConvert.SerializeObject |> RequestErrors.BAD_REQUEST

type Result<'T> =
| Success of 'T
| Failure of string

let DoThing someParam anotherParam =
    let stats = Success(999) // <- business code here
    match stats with
    | Success s -> s |> Ok
    | Failure m -> m |> NotOk
...
        let app =
            choose
                [ GET >=> choose
                    [
                        pathScan "/someroute/%i/%i" (fun (p1, p2) -> 
                                DoThing p1 p2)
                    ] 
                ]
        startWebServer config app
        0
```

I would like to check that the request contains a header with a certain name and value and return NotOk when it is absent or incorrect.  What's the simplest way to achieve this?

I'm a newcomer to Suave.io's compositional style.

Comment: you can look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31672110/suave-io-using-pathscan-and-request-together. I think you can than examine the request. Note: `type WebPart = HttpContext -> Async<HttpContext option>` and `type HttpContext = { request: HttpRequest; response: HttpResponse }`. So you need to unwrap the `WebPart`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that this would do what you need:

```
#r "Newtonsoft.Json.dll"
#r "Suave.dll"
#r "Suave.Testing.dll"
#r "System.Net.Http.dll"
#r "Fuchu.dll"

open System.Net
open System.Net.Http

open Suave
open Suave.Operators
open Newtonsoft.Json
open Suave.Filters
open Suave.Testing

let Ok o = o |> JsonConvert.SerializeObject |> Successful.OK
let NotOk o = o |> JsonConvert.SerializeObject |> RequestErrors.BAD_REQUEST

type Result<'T> =
| Success of 'T
| Failure of string

let DoThing someParam anotherParam =
    let stats = Success(999) // <- business code here
    match stats with
    | Success s -> s |> Ok
    | Failure m -> m |> NotOk

let checkHeader ctx =
    asyncOption {
        match "key" |> ctx.request.header with
        | Choice1Of2 k1 ->
            printfn "Header k1: %s" k1
            return ctx
        | Choice2Of2 k2 ->
            printfn "Header k2: %s" k2
            return { ctx with
                        response = { ctx.response with
                                        status = HTTP_400 } } }

let app =
    choose
        [ GET >=> choose
            [
                pathScan "/someroute/%i/%i" (fun (p1, p2) ->
                        DoThing p1 p2)
                >=> checkHeader
            ]
        ]

let emptyCont = new ByteArrayContent([||]) |> Some

runWith defaultConfig app
|> reqResp HttpMethod.GET 
           "/someroute/1/2" "" 
           None 
           None 
           DecompressionMethods.None
           id
           id
```

Make sure that you have the required libs in the same directory as this script and you can run it. Because there is no `key` header, the result will be a `BAD_REQUEST` with content 999.

The checkHeader does the trick.